# How to obtain Trusted URL in Extensibility Management

Tags: desire2learn

Please advise how to retrieve a Trusted URL for eLearn application so that I can use it to register an App in Manage Extensibility.

I registered successful an new app through Extensibility Management tool. System returns a pair App Id/Key. However when I use App Key/Id to retrieve User Key/Id through valence api tool (https://apitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com/), system gave me the error below.

"The request's 'x_target' value does not match the allowed values for this application. Contact your administrator."

I doubted that I provided wrong Trusted URL (https://elearnurl)

Thank you,
Khiem.

Answer (score 0):

Please read through these two blog articles on the Brightspace Developer Community:

https://community.brightspace.com/devcop/blog/keytool_update_whitelisting_is_here__find_out_what_it_means_to_you

https://community.brightspace.com/devcop/blog/whitelisting__app_registration_some_tips_out_of_the_gate

The key concept here is that you need to define what your Trusted URL value is. The Trusted URL value is best explained in the linked articles, but the short definition is this... The Trusted URL is the URL for which you will receive the provided User id/key pair.

If you are not properly using a Trusted URL value you will definitely see "x_target" errors.

Comment: Hi  Paul, thanks for your info. My main question is how to get or define Trusted URL from eLearn system.

Comment: Please note that I am create .NET batch job to call valence API so I need both App Id/Key and User Id/Key